# How do I compute correct planet oppositions?

Tags: python, astronomy, skyfield

I'm having a hard time to find a way to compute the exact moment when a planet comes in opposition. By definition, planet [image: P] is said to be in opposition when, from the point of view of Earth [image: E], it is at the opposite of the Sun [image: S], so my assumption was that it occurs at the moment when the angle [image: PES] was at its maximum value.

To find this, I wrote the following code with Skyfield:

```
def get_skf_objects():
    return get_loader()('de421.bsp')

def get_angle(time: Time):
    sun_pos = earth.at(time).observe(get_skf_objects()['sun'])
    aster_pos = earth.at(time).observe(get_skf_objects()[aster.skyfield_name]) # e.g. aster.skyfield_name = 'MARS'
    degrees = sun_pos.separation_from(aster_pos).degrees
    return degrees

get_angle.rough_period = 1.0

times, angles = _find_maxima(start_time, end_time, get_angle, epsilon=1./3600/24)
```

For some reasons I don't really get, this produces values for the times when a opposition actually happens. But my real problem is that, compared to the real opposition times, **the hour I get is always false**. For instance:

- Mars opposition of July 27, 2018 is given to be at 2:15 UTC, but in reality, it actually was at 5:12 UTC.
- Mars opposition of October 13, 2020 will happen at 23:59 UTC, but Skyfield tells me it will happen on October 14th at 01:55 UTC.

And so on…

I added print calls on the `degrees` variable in `get_angle` and on the `angles` after the call of `_find_maxima()` and got this result for October 14th:

```
[177.00547411 177.00728148 177.00435833 176.99671953 176.98440208
 176.96746426 176.94598429 176.92005866 176.88980009 176.85533528
 176.81680257 176.77434952]
[177.00547411 177.00615453 177.00667867 177.00704644 177.00725779
 177.00731269 177.00721115 177.00695318 177.00653883 177.00596817
 177.00524129 177.00435833]
[177.00725779 177.00727941 177.00729586 177.00730713 177.00731323
 177.00731417 177.00730993 177.00730051 177.00728593 177.00726617
 177.00724125 177.00721115]
[177.00731323 177.00731379 177.00731417 177.00731438 177.00731443
 177.0073143  177.00731399 177.00731352 177.00731288 177.00731207
 177.00731108 177.00730993]
[177.00731438 177.0073144  177.00731442 177.00731443 177.00731443
 177.00731443 177.00731442 177.00731441 177.00731439 177.00731436
 177.00731433 177.0073143 ]
[177.00731443 177.00731443 177.00731443 177.00731443 177.00731443
 177.00731443 177.00731443 177.00731443 177.00731443 177.00731443
 177.00731443 177.00731443]
[177.00731443 177.00731443 177.00731443 177.00731443 177.00731443
 177.00731443 177.00731443 177.00731443 177.00731443 177.00731443
 177.00731443 177.00731443]


[177.00731443]
```

What is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, but there are a few problems with your approach.

1. Your source for the exact time of opposition (did you mention the source? if so then I haven't yet found it in the text of your question) appears to be an incorrect one. The exact time of the 2020 Mars opposition is 23:25 UT, as you can verify at [this Google Books link](https://books.google.com/books?id=q2rSR_pRtYMC&pg=PA108&lpg=PA108&dq=what+time+mars+opposition+2020+october+13&source=bl&ots=65UnzRoZiy&sig=ACfU3U14urYp-2cBgPSzYg05aU3hZppHow&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjilre4k53mAhWFtVkKHTHLBdcQ6AEwFXoECBQQAQ#v=onepage&q=what%20time%20mars%20opposition%202020%20october%2013&f=false).
2. Your guess that opposition would be defined using the raw separation angle is close but not exact. According to [this article on the Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opposition_(astronomy)), opposition is the moment when the Sun's and the planet's ecliptic longitude are 180° away from each other. Among other things, this definition means that in the old days the moment of opposition could be found by subtracting two angles from a table of planetary longitudes, whereas a definition involving raw angular separation would have required spherical trigonometry between a pair of lat-lon (or RA-dec) coordinates.
3. The definition, as it happens, uses apparent positions, so you need to call `.apparent()` to transform the coordinates you receive.

Putting those adjustments together, see if the following script gives you the correct answer:

```
from skyfield.api import load, tau, pi
from skyfield.almanac import find_discrete

planets = load('de421.bsp')
sun = planets['sun']
earth = planets['earth']
mars = planets['mars']

ts = load.timescale(builtin=True)

def longitude_difference(t):
    e = earth.at(t)
    s = e.observe(sun).apparent()
    m = e.observe(mars).apparent()
    _, lon1, _ = s.ecliptic_latlon()
    _, lon2, _ = m.ecliptic_latlon()
    return (lon1.degrees - lon2.degrees) - 180 > 0

longitude_difference.rough_period = 300.0

t, b = find_discrete(ts.utc(2020), ts.utc(2021), longitude_difference)
for ti in t:
    print(t.utc_jpl())
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks for the precisions! FYI, the 23:59 UTC thing was a tiredness-related mistake, thanks for the correction :)

Comment: I'm glad it worked! Inspired by your question, the next version of Skyfield will have an official function for this calculation: https://github.com/skyfielders/python-skyfield/commit/600f75ddbacef813e57c922afac69c2738225c8e